# why Ubuntu is not detecting my wireless connection

Tags: wireless

I've moved from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm having problems with the detection of wireless connection. I can only connect using a cable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KW5G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIawj.png)

Comment: please replace the images by a copy/paste of the text.  Images we can not search, text we can.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.